# Square Bracket Wildcard not functioning when trying to make SQL selection in UcanAccess JDBC

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm making a project in Java that requires a selection query from an MS Access database using UCanAccess. When I try to create an SQL statement using [] brackets (in order to specify a list of chars as wildcards), I keep getting back 0 results. Here's the code (I use Guava library for the joiner class in order to make a string out of char array 'yellow'):

```
String y1 = Joiner.on("").join(yellow);
String q2 = "SELECT * FROM Wordlist WHERE Words LIKE '*["+y1+"]*'";
Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(q2);
int wcount1 = 0;
while (rs2.next()) {
    wcount1++;
}
System.out.println(wcount1);
```

My variable wcount1 comes up as zero whenever I run this program. The weird part is when I only use the * with variable y1 I get the correct number of records, but the square brackets keep showing up zero. Is this a syntax error? Do I need to do some kind of escape sequence?

Comment: what is the exact string in '*["+y1+"]*' in your example? Could you do a  System.out.println(y1);?

Comment: That brings up the String of whatever Chars I input in the previous portion of the program. For example, in my list I had ['a','u'] and y1 outputs to au.

Comment: I was trying to make sure that the like string is correctly formed
 Does it really have just `'*[au]*'` ? (And I assume your WordList table has words with letter a or u). Also, what does the like string look like when you used 'the * with variable y1'

Comment: The syntax ` LIKE '*[au]*'` works as intended in MsAccess. If the string is correct the only remaining suspect is your database library changing it before passing it onto the Jet engine.

Comment: Ah well a colleague of mine berrated me for using MS Access in the first place and recommended me to use MySQL or MariaDB instead. I'd been beating myself over this all day lol maybe tomorrow ill start using MySQL for this project instead. Thanks anyway mate,